# ModalViewController can not be released in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working with Xamarin.iOS. Now, when the user logged in successfully, the rootViewController will change from `LoginViewController` to `tabbarViewController`. My Login View has a page to check their phone number if this is the first time that the user logs in.

`loginViewController  --> (presenting ModalViewController) checkNumberViewController --> ( PushViewController )InputSMSViewController`

The problem is that after user authentication is completed. I dismiss the modalView and change the rootViewController. However, the LoginViewController can't be released. When I set the `View.alpha=0`. I can see the view on my device.

```
if(RESULT==checkResult.success)
{
   this.Window.RootViewController = CLGTabBarController;
   this.DismissViewController(false, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact .the code  `this.DismissViewController(false, null);` will not be called.You can change the rootViewController in the callback of the method `DismissViewController` . Try to use the following code：

```
if (RESULT == checkResult.success)
  {
    this.DismissViewController(false, () =>
     {
        this.Window.RootViewController = CLGTabBarController;
     } );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I will give that a try.